# element/object is NULL in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

```
var append = $('<li class="ui-widget-content" id="list-'+num+'">'+content+'</li>');
console.log( append ); // LOG: [object Object]
console.log( append.html() ); // LOG: null
```

IE 8 creates `var append` as an object but its html content is `null`. Works fine in other browsers. I can't figure out what's the problem here. Any ideas?

//edit//

`var content` is an ajax response html string, like this

```
<div class="item status-0 filiale-2" id="item-18">
            <div class="ui-corner-all date ui-state-active">
            <div class="filiale">D&uuml;ren</div>
            <div class="left date-add">22.06.2011 15:02:24 Uhr</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
            <form id="form-order-18" action=""">
                <input type="hidden" id="list-id" name="id" value="18" >
                <div class="relative left artikel"><input type="text" class="text ui-corner-all ui-widget-content autocomplete" id="list-artikel-18" name="artikel" value="79949 | ASUS Eee PC 1001PXD-BLK028S 25.65cm/N455/1" /></div>
                <div class="relative left qty">    <input type="text" class="text ui-corner-all ui-widget-content" id="list-qty-18" name="qty" value="1" /></div>
                <div class="relative left comment"><input type="text" class="text ui-corner-all ui-widget-content" id="list-comment-18" name="comment" value="kunde wünscht ungeöffnetes" /></div>
                <div class="relative left">
                <button type="button" class="item-edit" opt:icon="ui-icon-disk" opt:text="false">&Auml;nderungen speichern</button>
                <button type="button" class="item-del" item:id="18" opt:icon="ui-icon-trash" opt:text="false">Bestellung L&ouml;schen</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div>
            <form id="form-sendorder-18">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sendorder" />
                <input type="hidden" id="order-id" name="id" value="18" >
                <div class="relative left salesman">
                <label for="order-artikel-18" class="ui-state-disabled text">Händler</label>
                <input type="text" class="text ui-corner-all ui-widget-content acsalesman inlinefield" id="order-artikel-18" name="salesman" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="relative left dateexpected">
                <label for="order-list-date-expected-18" class="ui-state-disabled text">erwartet am</label>
                <input type="text" class="text ui-corner-all ui-widget-content inlinefield datepicker" id="order-list-date-expected-18" name="date_expected" value="" />
                </div>
                <div class="relative left comment">
                <label for="order-comment-18" class="ui-state-disabled text">Kommentar für Filiale</label>
                <input type="text" class="text ui-corner-all ui-widget-content inlinefield" id="order-comment-18" name="comment_o" value="" /></div>
                <div class="relative left">
                <button type="button" class="item-order" opt:icon="ui-icon-cart" opt:text="false" item:id="18">Ware Bestellt</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
```

this string is the problem. If I set the html without this string, it works.

```
var append = $('<li class="ui-widget-content" id="list-'+num+'">foobar</li>');
console.log( append ); // LOG: [object Object]
console.log( append.html() ); // LOG: foobar
```

Thanks & regards,

Alex

Comment: What is `content`? And which IE? There have been ten. [Works for me in IE8](http://jsfiddle.net/a698W/).

Comment: Try switching `console.log( append );` to `alert(append);`. Same with the other console.log. I have seen some versions of IE have heartburn with console.log. Worth a try; it's easy to do and it might help narrow down the problem.

Comment: i've edited the question. `var content` is the problem, maybe the specialchars...

Comment: or it could be the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

.html() in jQuery is an equivalent of innerHTML(), which means that in normal browsers (e.g FF, Chrome) it should get it right, while in IE you'll have to use the outerHTML property.

I'd try using the outerHTML jQuery plugin to get the element entirely: http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/

Hope it helps :)